# wmi: Property is returning null

Tags: c#, wmi, wmi-query

I'm trying to build a simple Windows Forms application that can query the capabilities of the user's computer using WMI (starting with the hard drives).

So far, I've got this far (`HardDriveCheckResult` is my own class):

```
ConnectionOptions wmiConnOpts = new ConnectionOptions();
wmiConnOpts.Impersonation = ImpersonationLevel.Impersonate;
wmiConnOpts.Authentication = AuthenticationLevel.Default;
wmiConnOpts.EnablePrivileges = true;
ManagementObjectSearcher managementObjectSearcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher(@"select * from Win32_LogicalDisk WHERE DriveType = 5");
managementObjectSearcher.Scope.Options = wmiConnOpts;
List<HardDriveCheckResult> hardDriveCheckResults = new List<HardDriveCheckResult>();

foreach (ManagementObject managementObject in managementObjectSearcher.Get())
{
    string hardDriveName = managementObject["name"].ToString();
    object objFreeSpace = managementObject["FreeSpace"];
    double freeSpace = objFreeSpace == null ? 0d : (double)objFreeSpace;
    ... additional code not relevant
}
```

The issue I'm having is that `managementObject["FreeSpace"]` always returns null. I suspect this may have something to do with the permissions of the account the WMI call is made with, hence my inclusion of the `ConnectionOptions` code which comes courtesy of Google.

Task Manager tells me the program is running as my account, which is an administrator, so I'm a bit stumped as to why the WMI calls wouldn't return all data.

Am I correct that the call to `managementObject["FreeSpace"]` returns null because of permissions? Or could it be something else entirely?

Oh, the call to `managementObject["name"]` correctly returns the drive letter by the way.

Comment: DriveType 5 is for CD's. If you are sure you didn't mean "select * from Win32_LogicalDisk WHERE DriveType != 5" >

Comment: Blimey, you guys are quick! And both right too! Sorry, it was my misuse of Google which was to blame. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, the answer is bad Googling. The query is filtering on DriveType = 5, which is CD-ROM drive. I thought I was filtering for hard drives.

The free space part was returning null because there was no disk in the drive.